# IMG SRC Using Path from MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, html, image

I have the following line of code which doesn't seem to be working:

```
echo "<img src='/images/albumart'"; echo $row['art1']; echo "/>";
```

The 'art1' is definitely returning '/imagename.png' so the URL should be complete however nothing being displayed.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: "not working" seems a little vague.  Is the html being generated correctly? Or is the image simply not displaying?

Answer (score 4):

You really should be concatenating that string:

```
<?php
echo '<img src="/images/albumart'.$row['art1'].'"/>'; 
?>
```

and ideally break out of php to do this:

```
<img src="/images/albumart<?php echo $row['art1']; ?>"/>
```

If you're not familiar, the period in php joins strings. That's called concatenation. No need to echo little bits like that, in fact please never do it the way you demonstrate. The root of your issue is, as Geoff pointed out, you weren't closing the src param.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<img src='/images/albumart'"; echo $row['art1']; echo "/>";
```

It looks like you are closing the img src paramter after the albumart part.,

try this:

```
echo "<img src='/images/albumart"; echo $row['art1']; echo "' />";
```

Comment: You're right about not closing the param, but man don't encourage this kind of behavior. no sane programmer would support his example. echoing out the image in segments like that. It's madness

Comment: He asked why it wasn't displaying, I told him. I'm well aware it's a completely crazy way to do it, but it will still work..